# Visualizing normal vectors

Tags: c++, graphics, computer-vision, vtk, point-clouds

I have some point cloud files in .xyz format. Each of these files contain approximately 1million points and corresponding normal vectors for each point. Each line of .xyz files belongs to one point and each line contains cartesian coordinates (x,y, and z) and normal vetor (nx,ny, and nz). My objective is to show points and their normal vectors. I can read .xyz files successfully and show points successfully. However, I can not show normal vectors successfully.
I tried to solve the problem using vtkGlyph3D class as shown in some examples of Kitware but every attempt was failure for me. My code is shown below.
Could you please help me about solving this problem? I am looking forward to hearing from you.
Thanks in advance

```
#include <vtkVersion.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkDelimitedTextReader.h>
#include <vtkDoubleArray.h>
#include <vtkTable.h>
#include <vtkPointData.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkVertexGlyphFilter.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDelimitedTextReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDelimitedTextReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName("points_and_normals.xyz");
    reader->DetectNumericColumnsOn();
    reader->SetFieldDelimiterCharacters(" ");
    reader->Update();

    vtkTable* table = reader->GetOutput();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDoubleArray> normals = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDoubleArray>::New();
    normals->SetNumberOfComponents(3); //3d normals (ie x,y,z)

    std::cout << "Table has " << table->GetNumberOfRows()
            << " rows." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Table has " << table->GetNumberOfColumns()
            << " columns." << std::endl;

    for (vtkIdType i = 0; i < table->GetNumberOfRows(); i++)
    {

            points->InsertNextPoint((table->GetValue(i, 0)).ToDouble(),
                    (table->GetValue(i, 1)).ToDouble(),
                    (table->GetValue(i, 2)).ToDouble());

            double n[3];
            n[0] = (table->GetValue(i, 3)).ToDouble();
            n[1] = (table->GetValue(i, 4)).ToDouble();
            n[2] = (table->GetValue(i, 5)).ToDouble();
            normals->InsertNextTuple(n);
    }

    std::cout << "There are " << points->GetNumberOfPoints()
            << " points." << std::endl;

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
    polydata->SetPoints(points);
    polydata->GetPointData()->SetNormals(normals);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkVertexGlyphFilter> glyphFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkVertexGlyphFilter>::New();
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
        glyphFilter->SetInputConnection(polydata->GetProducerPort());
#else
        glyphFilter->SetInputData(polydata);
#endif
    glyphFilter->Update();
    // Visualize
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(glyphFilter->GetOutputPort());
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);
    actor->GetProperty()->SetPointSize(3);
    actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(0, 0, 1);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
    renderer->AddActor(actor);
    renderer->SetBackground(.5, .5, .5);
    renderWindow->Render();
    renderWindowInteractor->Start();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: if you got `p` position and its `n`  normal then just render line `(p,p+size*n)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I tried it and it works great. However, it runs so slowly. Then I used openglglyph and it is much more faster.